# check when a client is disconnected

Tags: c#

I have a console application in c#
this code can tell me when a client si connected in TCP to port 3001 and the message sent 
I cant understand when he disconnects, its going into **while (client.Connected)**   unlimited, i tried to check with a PING but sometimes returns false even if connnected, 
I am stuck

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 3001;
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Listening on port " + port + "...");

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Accepted connection from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());


            while (client.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


                if (stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);


                    Console.WriteLine("Received data: " + data);
                }


                //check if client still connected
                string[] cli = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar(":"));
                string Host = cli[0];
                int Uri = port;// int.Parse(cli[1]);   
                if (PingHost(Host,Uri)==false) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }


    }




    public static bool PingHost(string hostUri, int portNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient(hostUri, portNumber))
                return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Error pinging host:'" + hostUri + ":" + portNumber.ToString() + "'");
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `client.Connected` is not telling you, what you think it is. Read carefully: _"true if the Client socket **was connected** to a remote resource **as of the most recent operation**; otherwise, false."_ - nothing more, nothing less. (Emphasis by me)

Comment: Your `PingHost` Method doesn't test the current connection, by the way. It just tells you if the remote host is still reachable. So, the only thing it can tell you about the current connection would be if it finds the remote host completely unreachable, then the probability that the current connection has been severed is close to 1.